# Are there any alternatives to ltrace that does the same job?

Tags: linux, c, ltrace

`ltrace` doesn't work on binaries linked with the `-z now` option—Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43213505/no-output-when-running-ltrace) question—which is the default on my Ubuntu 19.10 system. It only works on binaries linked with `-z lazy`.

Is there any alternative to `ltrace` that does the same job, but works on *lazily linked* binaries also?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61394462/alternative-to-ltrace-that-works-on-binaries-linked-with-z-now/61618754#61618754). I'll post a summary.

The [uftrace utility](https://github.com/namhyung/uftrace) is a valid alternative to ltrace that works on binaries linked with `-z now`. Below is a demonstration.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    printf("Hello world!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

We'll be using the above hello world program for demonstration purposes.

```
sumit@HAL9000:~$ gcc hello.c -o hello -Wl,-z,now
sumit@HAL9000:~$ ltrace ./hello 
Hello world!
+++ exited (status 0) +++
sumit@HAL9000:~$ uftrace --force -a ./hello
Hello world!
# DURATION     TID     FUNCTION
 187.291 us [ 40352] | puts("Hello world!") = 13;
```

As we can see above, `ltrace` didn't work on the program when it was compiled with `-z now`, but `uftrace` did.